# gitweb alternative for simply hosting source code

Tags: display

I would like to simply publish a project's source code on a server.

Currently gitweb works well, except I don't need the extra revisions features, and there is some configuring needed such as setting project descriptions. Also, it doesn't have syntax highlighting

Basically, are there any alternatives that let you browse source code like gitweb does?

Things like trac are overkill for just displaying source code. I'd like something simple.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use [cgit](http://hjemli.net/git/cgit/) to host many different subprojects under one interface. cgit does caching so it can be much faster than gitweb which needs to parse the projects all the time. In fact cgit powers e.g. the [Gnome project's repositories web-frontend](http://git.gnome.org/browse/). Cgit can do source highlighting with `highlight`, but it should be possible to use something like `pygments` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Why not host on [github](http://github.com)? They may provide more features than you need, but their syntax highlighting is nice, and assuming your project is open-source, it's free.  Otherwise, see the last section of [the git wiki entry for gitweb](https://git.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Gitweb) for a list of other web interfaces, one of them might suit your needs.

Comment: One reason that you might want to run something like gitweb or cgit is for an internal server, so that people can browse the source code on the internal network but it's not public like github is.

Comment: Sure, I can see that. Github also has private repos, although they cost a (minimal) amount of money if you just need a few.